# Increase width and height on html viewer model

Tags: html, model-viewer

Currently when I upload the code below into an HTML component on my site the content is constrained to a small box, however there is far more space in the html component to fit the content.

Can someone please let me know what and where to write the code that would be most appreciated!

```
<script type="module" 
        src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer.min.js"></script>

<model-viewer 
       alt="Neil Armstrong's Spacesuit from the Smithsonian Digitization Programs Office and National Air and Space Museum" 
       src="shared-assets/models/NeilArmstrong.glb" 
       ar ar-modes="webxr scene-viewer quick-look" 
       environment-image="shared-assets/environments/moon_1k.hdr" 
       poster="shared-assets/models/NeilArmstrong.webp" 
       seamless-poster shadow-intensity="1" camera-controls>
</model-viewer>
```

Comment: <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer.min.js"></script>

<model-viewer alt="Neil Armstrong's Spacesuit from the Smithsonian Digitization Programs Office and National Air and Space Museum" src="shared-assets/models/NeilArmstrong.glb" ar ar-modes="webxr scene-viewer quick-look" environment-image="shared-assets/environments/moon_1k.hdr" poster="shared-assets/models/NeilArmstrong.webp" seamless-poster shadow-intensity="1" camera-controls></model-viewer>

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML, markup or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Have you got any CSS effecting model-viewer

Comment: no however the html component allows for style inputs I just don't know the code I have tried to put the following pretty much everywhere in the code to try and effect it

Comment: <style> {Width 600px; height 800px;}</style>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increase a model-viewer box width and height then you can easily apply a css on model-viewer tag.

```
    model-viewer{
         width:400px;
         height:400px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**I had this exact same problem also**

> the content is constrained to a small box, however there is far more space in the html component to fit the content.

**The solution for me was to do the following:**

Wrap the model-viewer in an empty div and
apply CSS to the DIV and the model-viewer that achieved the styling I desired.

**Notes**

When I tried using the following values for width on the model-viewer it would not style correctly.

```
width: auto;
width: 100%;
```

**HTML below**

```
<div class="model-view-css-fix">
      <model-viewer 
       alt="Neil Armstrong's Spacesuit from the Smithsonian Digitization Programs Office and National Air and Space Museum" 
       src="shared-assets/models/NeilArmstrong.glb" 
       ar ar-modes="webxr scene-viewer quick-look" 
       environment-image="shared-assets/environments/moon_1k.hdr" 
       poster="shared-assets/models/NeilArmstrong.webp" 
       seamless-poster shadow-intensity="1" camera-controls>
      </model-viewer>
</div>
```

**CSS below**

The width would fail to style correctly with 100% or auto therefore a 50% width to height ratio is maintained by vh.

```
.model-view-css-fix{
  object-fit: contain;
  height: 80vh;
  width:auto;  
}
model-viewer {
  width: 40vh;
  height: 80vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap `model-viewer` in a `div` and set the `height` and `width` attributes with the `inherit` value. Make sure `div`s have `height` and `width` set to an initial value of your choice.

```
div{
    height: 50vh;
    width: 50vw;
}
model-viewer{
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked perfectly for my case:

```css
.wrapper{
width: 500px;
height: 300px;
}
model-viewer{
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
        <div class="wrapper">
          <!--3D Model goes inside this div-->
          
          <model-viewer 
          ar 
          ar-modes="webxr" 
          camera-controls
          disable-pan
          disable-zoom
          min-camera-orbit="auto 80deg auto"
          max-camera-orbit="auto 80deg auto"
          touch-action="none"
          src="male.gltf"
          shadow-intensity="1"
          alt="3d Human Model"
          camera-orbit="18.9deg 77.33deg 0.703m"
          camera-target="-0.00m 0.175m 0.00m"
          field-of-view="33deg"
          max-field-of-view="33deg"
          min-field-of-view="17deg"
          interpolation-decay="300">

        </div>
```